# TemplateSyntaxError, Could not parse the remainder:

Tags: django

template.html

```
{% with category2Choices=form.category2.field.choices.queryset.values_list("value", "display_name", "parent_id")|list %}
<script>
  var category2Choices = JSON.parse('{{ category2Choices|json_script:"category2Choices" }}');
</script>
{% endwith %}
```

I am getting this issue: TemplateSyntaxError at /pages/add_product/
Could not parse the remainder: '("value",' from 'form.category2.field.choices.queryset.values_list("value",'

I want to initially populate the main categories in a select field. When the user selects a main category, I want to dynamically fetch and display the subcategories related to that main category. To achieve this, I am using a small JavaScript code.

Can you help me?